# Powershell module initialization

Tags: powershell, module

Does PowerShell call any initialization code when a module is loaded?

I am looking for something like a Perl BEGIN block, or a constructor.

Both NEW-MODULE and IMPORT-MODULE will return a PSCustomObject. I am trying to encapsulate a custom object in a module to avoid lengthy code in scripts. One method that tests well in open code is:

```
$m = new-module -scriptblock {
New-Object PSCustomObject | 
    Add-Member NoteProperty -name person -value Frodo -passthru | 
    Add-Member ScriptMethod Who { $this.person }  -passthru |
    Add-Member ScriptMethod Mod { 
        param($x)
        $this.person = $x
        } -passthru
} -ascustomobject -returnresult
```

Ideally I would like to drop this code into a module and use something like:

```
$MyObj = Import-Module -Name ".\MyPackage" -AsCustomObject
```

and have MyObj be a handle to an object the same as the first snippet provides.

Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

It's not clear if you want to run initialization code when a module is loaded (like Perl's BEGIN block) or if you want to create a custom class (which is what "constructor" suggests).

Initialization code in a module is easy. Any code in a module not embedded in a function is executed when the module is imported.

Creating a custom class isn't supported natively in PS. But see: http://psclass.codeplex.com/. You can also write C#, VBScript, etc. and use Add-Type.

Import-module won't work to simulate a class, because you can only have 1 instance of a module with a given name - at best you'd have a singleton class. (BTW, import-module does have a -passthru parameter, which would more or less make your last line of code work - as a singleton. You'd also have to add `export-module -variable * -function *` to your module code) You could use New-Module to simulate a class though. And you could wrap it in a function named, `new-myClass` for example.

BTW, if you use the -ASCustomObject parameter you end up with a hashtable, which doesn't support "this" (in words hash table values that are script blocks don't have a built-in way to refer to the hashtable itself). If you use new-module without -AsCustomObject (and potentially use a factory function, for example new-myclass) then you could simulate "this.varInMyModule" with `& $myModule $varInMyModule`. However if you create a PSCustomObject, using Add-Member, then script method have access to $this and it in general acts a lot more like a typical object with properties and methods.

Comment: Do you have a link to documentation confirming "Any code in a module not embedded in a function is executed when the module is imported." I believe this is a half truth: modules written in PowerShell work this way, modules written in C# do not seem to have a way to do this (unless you edit CIL and add .ModuleInit, such as with Fody post-build handler, because ModuleInit is not common language specification compliant).

Answer (score 2):

Modules are really supposed to output cmdlets, not objects. A module should provide a set of related cmdlets. There is a way to send data into the module using `Import-Modules`'s `-ArgumentList` parameter as show [here](http://www.nivot.org/blog/post/2009/10/22/PowerShell20ModuleInitializers). You could use the technique to provide a server name for  your cmdlets to connect to for example. The PowerCLI module handles that differently using a cmdlet that creates a script scope connection object (`$script:connection`) that the other cmdlets check for and re-use if it exists similar to this:

```
#test.psm1
$script:myvar = "hi"
function Show-MyVar {Write-Host $script:myvar}
function Set-MyVar ($Value) {$script:myvar = $Value}
#end test.psm1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Modules you can export both innate properties and functions, and don't need to run them through add-member or do much acrobatics.  Note however that it has some issues if you don't want to export all properties and methods, and while *you can initialize properties* to an initial value, you CAN'T call an *internal function* during initialization without doing some akward acrobatics.

But I think what you really want to do is use Classes which are now available in Powershell 5 (they weren't when you posted).  I've provided examples of each. 
 Sysops has a [decent tutorial](https://4sysops.com/archives/powershell-classes-part-1-objects/) on the new classes in 4 parts

Here's the older way before powershell 5.0

```
# powershell 3.0 and above (I think)
$m = new-module -ascustomobject -scriptblock `
    {
    $person = "Frodo"
    function Who
        ()
        {return $this.person}
    function Rename
        ($name)
        {$this.person = $name}
    Export-ModuleMember -Function * -Variable *
    }

write-host "direct property access: $($m.person)"
write-host "method call: $($m.who())"
$m.Rename("Shelob")
write-host "change test: $($m.who())"
```

Also you can replicate multiple objects from a template like this:

```
# powershell 3.0 and above (I think)
$template = `
    {
    $person = "Frodo"
    function Who
        ()
        {return $this.person}
    function Rename
        ($name)
        {$this.person = $name}
    Export-ModuleMember -Function * -Variable *
    }

$me = new-module -ascustomobject -scriptblock $template; $me.Rename("Shelob")
$you = new-module -ascustomobject -scriptblock $template

"Me: $($me.Who())"
"You: $($you.Who())"
```

And in powershell 5 you have actual classes (mostly)

```
#requires -version 5
Class Person
    {
    hidden [String] $name #not actually private

    [string] Who ()
        {return $this.name}

    [void] Rename ([string] $name)
        {$this.name = $name}

    # constructors are weird though, you don't specify return type OR explicitly return value.
    Person ([String]$name)
        {$this.name = $name}
    <#
    # The above constructor code is secretly converted to this
    [Person] New ([string]$name) #note the added return type and renamed to New
        {
        $this.name = $name
        return $this #note that we are returning ourself, you can exploit this to create chained constructors like [person]::New("gandalf").withWizardLevel("White") but I haven't done so here
        }
    #>

    }
$me = [Person]::new("Shelob")
$you = [Person]::new("Frodo")

# $me|gm        # Note that Name doesn't show here
# $me.name      # But we can still access it...
# $me|gm -Force # Note that Name DOES show here

"`n"
"Me: $($me.who())"
"You: $($you.who())"
$you.Rename("Dinner")
"You after we meet: $($you.who())"
```