# Is it possible to have helper modules?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-module

I am having number of advanced functions in PowerShell which is dealing with version numbers which is core part of our configuration module.

When the user imports the configuration module these functions should be available to them. I could copy all the functions to the configuration module, but if it is kept like helper module, it will be very good to organize.

The end user should only import main configuration module but this helper module should be included to that. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: You can create some sort of linking i.e. when main module is imported, the code inside main module will silently import helper one. [How to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625425/powershell-module-initialization)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the helper module as a "nested module" in your [Module Manifest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878337%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
@{
  ModuleToProcess   = 'Configuration.psm1'
  ModuleVersion     = '1.0'
  GUID              = '7ec463d6-de22-40bb-a505-1efcb3b22b73'
  Author            = 'Ansgar Wiechers'
  Description       = 'Configuration Module'
  PowerShellVersion = '2.0'

  FunctionsToExport = '*'
  CmdletsToExport   = '*'
  VariablesToExport = '*'
  AliasesToExport   = '*'

  NestedModules     = 'Helper'
}
```

The helper module doesn't actually have to be nested. You can place both modules as individual modules:

```
WindowsPowerShell
`-Modules
  +-Configuration
  | +-Configuration.psd1
  | `-Configuration.psm1
  `-Helper
    +-Helper.psd1
    `-Helper.psm1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make them both available as cmdlets by creating another PS Module Path and placing them there - this will be available in every PS session to all users. all they have to do `Import-Module` and all functions will become available.

Inside Modules, you can have folders named the same as the .psm1 file inside e.g. `Modules/Configuration/Configuration.psm1` & `Modules/Helper/Helper.psm1`.

```
if (!(Test-Path $Profile.AllUsersAllHosts)) {
  $profile_new1 = New-Item -Type File -Path $Profile.AllUsersAllHosts -Force
  Add-Content $profile_new1 '$env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + ";C:\Temp\Modules"'
} else {
  $profile_exist = Get-Item $Profile.AllUsersAllHosts
  Add-Content $profile_exist '$env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + ";C:\Temp\Modules"'
}
```